# Call multiple rest service link at sametime in android

Tags: java, android, rest, listview

I have android music app which have multiple section in it like latest music upcoming music popular music etc. how i can implement multiple rest link on android app start to fill these section lists ?

Comment: Use retrofit from square. 
Create urls for each REST API endpoints and call them to fill those sections

Comment: i am allready using retrofit but how should i create logic should i create logic like one response completed then another request start then third then fourth? or how i can implement those multiple request sametime. any suggestion how i can implement this in my music app?

Answer (score 1):

Using retrofit or any 3rd party API that supports Rest interface consumption. If your sections are dependent on one another, make the request for next section in call back. Or if not dependent, may be use separate threads to invoke services and in each call back, render the response accordingly on the view. Without code, this is the only help I can provide :)

Comment: can you give me a short example for separate thread for each section because they are not dependent to each other i have to call them at the sametime.